# Нужно удалить тег целиком, если его содержимое совпадает

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите с регуляркой.
Нужно удалить тег и текст в нем.

Например есть строка

```
<script src="/test.js"></script>
<script src="/test2.js?country=pt&label=true"></script>
```

Нужно удалить

```
<script src="/test2.js?country=pt&label=true"></script>
```

Так же ссылка в теге может быть без параметров, или параметры другие в ней, то тоже нужно определить test2.js и удалить полностью тег script и его содержимое.

Comment: [`~<script\h+src="/?test2\.js[^"]*"></script>~`](https://regex101.com/r/7af6Z3/1) **UPD:** если понадобятся пояснения - напишу пост в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант:

```php
$subject = '
<script src="/test.js"></script>
<script src="/test2.js?country=pt&label=true"></script>
';

$pattern = '=<script .*?src\="/test2\.js\??.*?".*></script>=';

$replacement = '';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);

echo $result;
```

- https://replit.com/@w3lifer/SoftDutifulLinux#main.php

Answer (score 0):

дай ему класс например hello, после обратись к нему document.querySelector('.hello') и удали его document.querySelector('.hello').remove() Также можешь при каких то событий это сделать!

Comment: Он всё равно будеи скачиваться, но идея хорошая ... 1) https://i.imgur.com/E1UrCbG.png; 2) https://i.imgur.com/xTaWX46.png; 3) https://i.imgur.com/1p2dxVt.png.